# How to aggregate timestamp data in Spark to smaller time frame

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, timestamp, aggregation

I'm working on a project using New York taxi data. The data contain records for pickup location (`PULocationID`), and the timestamp (`tpep_pickup_datetime`) for that particular pick-up record.

[image: sample of the data]

I want to aggregate the data to be hourly for each location. The aggregation should have an hourly count of pick-ups per location.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you provided is a bit lacking. From what I understood, these could be possible aggregation options.

Using [`date_trunc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.groupBy(
        F.date_trunc('hour', 'tpep_pickup_datetime').alias('hour'),
        'PULocationID',
    ).count()

df.show()
# +-------------------+------------+-----+
# |               hour|PULocationID|count|
# +-------------------+------------+-----+
# |2020-01-01 00:00:00|         238|    1|
# |2020-01-01 02:00:00|         238|    2|
# |2020-01-01 02:00:00|         193|    1|
# |2020-01-01 01:00:00|         238|    2|
# |2020-01-01 00:00:00|           7|    1|
# +-------------------+------------+-----+
```

Using [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.groupBy(
        F.window('tpep_pickup_datetime', '1 hour').alias('hour'),
        'PULocationID',
    ).count()

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------+------------+-----+
# |hour                                      |PULocationID|count|
# +------------------------------------------+------------+-----+
# |[2020-01-01 02:00:00, 2020-01-01 03:00:00]|238         |2    |
# |[2020-01-01 01:00:00, 2020-01-01 02:00:00]|238         |2    |
# |[2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-01 01:00:00]|238         |1    |
# |[2020-01-01 02:00:00, 2020-01-01 03:00:00]|193         |1    |
# |[2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-01 01:00:00]|7           |1    |
```